# Applying DivisorSigma to each element in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Take a simple `Table`

```
table = Table[n^2, {n, 1, 10}]
```

> `{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100}`

I want to apply the function `DivisorSigma[1, #]` to each element of `table` to create a new list / table with `10` entries. (The `1` specifies the sum-of-divisors function; I'm using `#` in a non-literal way, just to signify that I want to apply the function to each element of `table` separately.)

I assume I need to use either `Map` or `Apply`, or a combination of both. But because `DivisorSigma` requires two arguments, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Try `Map[DivisorSigma[1,#] &, table]`.

Comment: Hi @b.gates.you.know.what... I could have sworn I'd tried that - but now it works! I was obviously doing something stupid... Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Why not just `DivisorSigma[1, table]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
table = Table[n^2, {n, 1, 10}]
```

A couple of ways. Note that `#` only applies to the numbers included in `table`. The second argument to `DivisorSigma` is fixed.

```
Map[DivisorSigma[1, #] &, table]
(* {1, 7, 13, 31, 31, 91, 57, 127, 121, 217} *)
```

I frequently like to use `Table` rather than `Map` as it is more readable.

```
Table[DivisorSigma[1, it], {it, table}]
(* {1, 7, 13, 31, 31, 91, 57, 127, 121, 217} *)
```

Comment: I think you meant to write `DivisorSigma[1, #]`, not `DivisorSigma[#, 1]`.